# PHP Mysqli Slow but fast on Native Database

Tags: php, performance, mysqli

Good evening,

I am seeing something that I would really appreciate some help with.  We have a data table that receives a json output from a php script.  This php script is basically our php call to fetch data from the database and load it in a json array.  The sql statement is very long query but it takes about 1 second to run when i run it native on the database with SQLYog.  But I noticed the other day that the php version of the same query is taking in the upwards of 15 seconds.  I know it is 15 seconds because i used the following code and the results are that this fetch is taking about 15 seconds.  Please note I have simplified the claim for the sake of this conversation.
As you will note, I have tried 3 different methods to "fetch" this data.

1. fetch_all
2. fetch_array
3. fetch_row

Any help with this would be appreciated.  One more note, I am running php 5.6 and mysql 5.7 on Ubuntu.

```
$OutputArray['data'] = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $OutputArray['data'] = $row;
}

while ($row = $result->fetch_row_assoc)
{
    $OutputArray['data'] = $row;
}
```

```
$BeginTime = microtime(true);
$EndTime1 = microtime(true);

$diff1 = $EndTime1 - $BeginTime;
$Seconds1 = intval($diff1);
$MicroSeconds1 = $diff1 - $Seconds1;


$GetDataQuery = "SELECT Claims.* FROM tbl_claims Claims";

if (!$result = $mysqli->query($GetDataQuery))
{
    $ErrorCount = $ErrorCount + 1;
    $Error .= "Filename: " . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
}
else
{
    $OutputArray = array();

    // while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    // {
    //  $OutputArray['data'] = $row;
    // }    

    // while ($row = $result->fetch_row_assoc)
    // {
    //  $OutputArray['data'] = $row;
    // }

    $OutputArray['data'] = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($OutputArray);
```

}

Comment: Right now it's impossible to answer this question because it features some random code sketch, that measures literally nothing. Please provide the **actual** code and **actual** output. especially the number of rows returned

Comment: Guys, thank you for the heads up.  I am sorry, I did not included the actual query.  There is some sensitive data there that I could not include without having to redo the query to hide the the sensitive data.  But, I do want to thank you for making me think about it again this morning.  I have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but I have just figured out the problem.  I had the "Limit Rows" feature of sqlyog turned on and it turns out that the query is exponentially slower when the rows go from 1000 to 4000k. But at least I know that the PHP and the database match each other.
Thank you.